# How do I solve unsupported type ImageView error?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have two xml files. One in layout-land and the other in layout. However

```
"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

is marked red. I don't know if these are connected? Furthermore, as said I have the error unsupported type 'imageview'. Any help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance.

p.s. I am a newbie at java programming, started this week. Another p.s. is I use android studio ide

Comment: Post your xml layout files

Comment: Use "ImageView" instead of "imageview"

Comment: xml layout files posted. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Can you Add any Code Sample.
if the error as you side in your question.
I think it is because of using imageview which starts with small letters 
instead of using ImageView which starts with capital letters.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mustache"
        android:id="@+id/snorAfbeelding"            
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I update your edits to contain ImageView Sample only. not whole layout @Thenoobienoob

Answer (score 1):

There is no Imageview in Android. Try ImageView (case sensitive).

Answer (score -1):

Can you please post some code. Using ImageView in place of Imageview might solve your problem.